# Owners not receiving email when added to a group in Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I create a group in graph with the following body:

```
{
  "description": "<GroupDescription>",
  "displayName": "<GroupTitle>",
  "groupTypes": [
    "Unified"
  ],
  "mailEnabled": true,
  "mailNickname": "<SiteName>",
  "owners@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>"
  ],
  "securityEnabled": false,
  "visibility": "private"
}
```

None of the owners added with the code:

```
"owners@odata.bind": [
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>",
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userID>"
      ]
```

receive an email. Users added to the group later will receive one. Is there a way to make the owners receive a welcome-email when added during the group creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unified Group Welcome Message is only sent to new members. If you would like to notify them that they've been added to a Group, you can add them to both `owners` and `members`.

This is also the [guidance for Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0):

> We recommend that when you add an owner, you also add that user as a member. If a team has an owner who is not also a member, ownership and membership changes might not show up immediately in Microsoft Teams. In addition, different apps and APIs will handle that differently. For example, Microsoft Teams will show teams that the user is either a member or an owner of, while the Microsoft Teams PowerShell cmdlets and the /me/joinedTeams API will only show teams the user is a member of. To avoid confusion, add all owners to the members list as well.